# Map Tidymodels process to a list/group by or nest

Tags: r, purrr, tidymodels

I REALLY like tidymodels, but I'm unclear how I could fit that model workflow on something like a nested group by.  As an example, tidyr outlines a simple nest on something like cylinder from mtcars, and then fits a unique linear reg model to each cylinder.  I'm trying to fit hundreds of unique models (likely a random forest) based on something like cylinder, but using the tidymodels workflow (data split, recipe, predict).

Here's what is outlined on the tidyr page as a simple nest/fit linear reg:

```
mtcars_nested <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()

mtcars_nested <- mtcars_nested %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, function(df) lm(mpg ~ wt, data = df)))
mtcars_nested
```

Is there a way to do something like the below, but based on a group_by or nest attribute in a column?  The predictions and/or accuracy would then need to be combined for each and stored in one dataframe, if possible.  I tried feeding the data split a nested dataframe, and it didn't work. I feel like this is a purrr map question, but am unclear if it's something tidymodels already supports:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)

#add dataset
mtcars <- mtcars

#create data splits
split <- initial_split(mtcars)
mtcars_train <- training(split)
mtcars_test <- testing(split)

#create recipe
mtcars_recipe <-
  recipe(mpg ~., data = mtcars_train) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

#define model
lm_mod <-
  linear_reg(mode = "regression") %>%
  set_engine("lm")

#create workflow that combines recipe & model
mtcars_workflow <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(lm_mod) %>%
  add_recipe(mtcars_recipe)

#fit workflow on train data
mtcars_fit <-
  fit(mtcars_workflow, data = mtcars_train)

#predict on test data
predictions <-
predict(mtcars_fit, mtcars_test)
```

Appreciate help/advice/direction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can definitely do this if you want! I would set up a function to do all the tidymodels fitting and predicting that you need, and then `map()` through your nested dataframes.

First define any things that you prefer outside your function, and then create your function.

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.0      ✓ recipes   0.1.13
#> ✓ dials     0.0.8      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.0      ✓ tibble    3.0.3 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.2      ✓ tidyr     1.1.0 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.3      ✓ tune      0.1.1 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.0.2      ✓ workflows 0.1.2 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.2      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()

## some example data to use
data("hpc_data")

hpc_data <- hpc_data %>%
  select(-protocol, -class)

lm_mod <-
  linear_reg(mode = "regression") %>%
  set_engine("lm")

wf <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(lm_mod)

## big function of model fitting and predicting
predict_hpc <- function(df) {
  split <- initial_split(df)
  train_df <- training(split)
  test_df <- testing(split)
  
  #create recipe
  recipe_train <-
    recipe(compounds ~., data = train_df) %>%
    step_normalize(all_predictors())
  
  #fit workflow on train data
  fit_wf <-
    wf %>%
    add_recipe(recipe_train) %>%
    fit(data = train_df)
  
  #predict on test data
  predict(fit_wf, test_df) 
  
}
```

Now you can nest your data, and then `map()` over these nested dataframes with your function. It's a good idea to use a [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) adverb like `possibly()` to catch failures nicely.

```r
hpc_nested <- hpc_data %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  nest()

hpc_nested %>%
  mutate(predictions = map(data, possibly(predict_hpc, otherwise = NA)))
#> Timing stopped at: 0.001 0 0.001
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#> # Groups:   day [7]
#>   day   data               predictions       
#>   <fct> <list>             <list>            
#> 1 Tue   <tibble [900 × 5]> <tibble [225 × 1]>
#> 2 Thu   <tibble [720 × 5]> <tibble [180 × 1]>
#> 3 Fri   <tibble [923 × 5]> <tibble [230 × 1]>
#> 4 Wed   <tibble [903 × 5]> <tibble [225 × 1]>
#> 5 Mon   <tibble [692 × 5]> <tibble [173 × 1]>
#> 6 Sat   <tibble [32 × 5]>  <lgl [1]>         
#> 7 Sun   <tibble [161 × 5]> <tibble [40 × 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In this case it failed for Saturday, probably because there was so little data on Saturday to start with.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It's exactly what I was looking to do.  I really appreciate all the work you and the team have put in to tidymodels.  Your tidy Tuesday videos are great as well!