# How do you create a model for multiple levels of a response variable (such as a model for each city in a data set)?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-modeling, modeling, tidymodels

I have been following along with this tutorial:

https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/models/parsnip-ranger-glmnet/

This is an example for modeling with the `ames` housing data from `tidymodels` in which house sale prices are predicted. While this data only pertains to housing in Ames, I am curious - what if there was data for multiple cities? How would I create a model for each city? Is there a way to create a model to predict house sales for each city with Tidymodels without manually separating the data out into separate data frames for each city and running the model?

Maybe a `group_by` type of thing before

```
rand_forest(mode = "regression", mtry = 3, trees = 1000) %>%
  set_engine("ranger") %>%
  fit(
    log10(Sale_Price) ~ Longitude + Latitude + Lot_Area + Neighborhood + Year_Sold,
    data = ames_train
  )
```

TLDR:
If I am trying to predict house sales and want a model for each city (like in the table I made below), how is that specified with Tidymodels?

| City | Date | Sale | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ames | 2020-02-02 | 150000 | Neighborhood |
| Ames | 2020-02-5 | 170000 | Neighborhood |
| New York | 2020-02-20 | 1750000 | Urban |
| New York | 2020-02-13 | 1200000 | Urban |

Comment: In the page you link to, right after the first fit there's a reference to *dummy variables*. Isn't it what the question is about? In R, many fitting functions coerce to factor and create the dummies automatically.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687664/map-tidymodels-process-to-a-list-group-by-or-nest), but I don't want to use the close hammer in case it is not what you looking for.

Comment: I think it may be. Thank you. I do have a question though - how do I unnest the values to see what the predictions are? I'm new to this.

Comment: If you had information on city, you would use that as a predictor, like `log10(Sale_Price) ~ Longitude + Latitude + Lot_Area + Year_Sold + City`. When you make a prediction, you would include `City` as one of your predictors. There isn't any need to unnest or do any special data wrangling. (You probably could _not_ include both neighborhood and city as predictors, since you would have neighborhoods that are only in distinct cities.)